# Amazon Cognito Duplicate Usernames

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm investigating Amazon Cognito to see if it's feasible to migrate my existing application over to. However, I'm struggling to find documentation as to how it will handle my specific use case. Our users belong to an organization. Within an organization they cannot have the same username, but a username can be the same across different organizations.

For example, say we have Foo Inc. and Bar Inc. Alice wants to sign up for both organizations. She can have a username called "alice123" in both Foo Inc. and Bar Inc.

Is there a way to handle passing around a organization id as a third field of authorization? Our current system to log in one needs the username, password, and organization id to authenticate in.

Thanks,

Comment: do you find any solution for this using Cognito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use just one user pool with all the unique usernames.
The organizations that a user might belong to could be kept in a custom cognito field.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html
Or alternatively it could be stored in a different table (in RDS for example)
The relation of userids and organizations should be handled by your application code, it's not something that cognito is designed to handle

Comment: This doesn't solve for `username can be the same across different organizations`... cognito won't allow the same username even if the custom cognito field is different

Comment: Cognito doesn't support duplicate usernames. This is the reason the answer suggests to add "organization" property as a custom cognito field and handle this in yr application code.  The answer does not suggest that adding a custom field will allow you to add duplicate usernames. Just keep the organization of each user in cognito (or dynamo or rds etc) and to do the proper routing in yr code.